# How can i run already existing virtual enviroment that i created earlier?

Tags: virtual-environment

I am learning Django, I know how to create virtual Env. but i don't know how to reactivate it .
if i use this command -

> mkvirtualenv test

then i get this message-

> ERROR: virtualenv "test" already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `workon` to switch to a virtual env that already exists:

```
$ workon test
```

Comment: What if i created more than 1 virtual env , will it impact something ??

Comment: virtualenv is designed to allow you to create multiple environments and change each one differently si you can test things without breaking your main environment. The only impact is the extra space it may take.